# How to query a table with cardinality one to display all the Pk while also displaying the matching elements in a table with FK

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**First of all, please forgive me if the question is not clear. I will explain it clearly here.**

Ok, lets say, I have a table "TableA" with columns, (ApkColumn, x, y) where ApkColumn is the primary key for TableA and lets say "TableA" has following info:

**TableA**

***ApkColumn|| x || y ||***

1        || Bob || Alan

2        || Linda || berry

3        || Andrew || Hall

and

and another table "Table B" with columns, (BpkColumn, M,N, AfkColumn) where BpkColumn is the Primary key for TableB and AfkColumn is the foreign key to Table A.

**TableB**

***BpkColumn||M||N||AfkColumn***

1           ||Physics01||Fundamentals of physics|| 1

Now, I want to query A such that I should get results like this:

**result table**

***x||M||N***

**Bob||Physics01||Fundamentals of physics**

**Linda||null||null**

**Andrew|| null||null**

i.e. I want to display all the elements from TableA (for a column) and if it have a corresponding column in TableB, it should be displayed else, null should be displayed.

I tried to do a left join against the PK and FK. But, it displays only for the columns in tableB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have been nice to add the query you made cause what you suggested is the way to do it. just make sure that Table A is on the left side of the join:

```
select .....
from A left outer join B
on (A.ApkColumn=B.AfkColumn)
```

Comment: You got me! I was using only join, not outer join. Thanks for your help!